# How to stop changing the values according to the NumberPicker automatically in AndroidStudio?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-room

I tried to make a simple stock inventory application which allows to add/view/update/delete using this tutorial as the base(https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/room-viewmodel-livedata-recyclerview-mvvm/part-1-introduction) which uses Room, ViewModel, LiveData to store data in SQLlite db. The problem is, whenever I try to open a “note” or “listing”, the “Quantity” and “Price” automatically sets itself equal to the “Priority” value. On trying to edit an individual listing, I can only update the "string" types ie. description and title while Price and Quantity which are of "int" types remain the same as the set priority from numberPicker.

I am very new to coding so any help or a hint of direction to proceed would be very appreciated.

Here's my AddEditNoteActivity.java:

```
public class AddEditNoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_ID =
        "com.example.stock_management.EXTRA_ID";
public static final String EXTRA_TITLE =
        "com.example.stock_management.EXTRA_TITLE";
public static final String EXTRA_DESCRIPTION =
        "com.example.stock_management.EXTRA_ID.EXTRA_DESCRIPTION";
public static final String EXTRA_PRIORITY =
        "com.example.stock_management.EXTRA_ID.EXTRA_PRIORITY";
public static final String EXTRA_PRICE =
        "com.example.stock_management.EXTRA_ID.EXTRA_PRIORITY";
public static final String EXTRA_QUANTITY =
        "com.example.stock_management.EXTRA_ID.EXTRA_PRIORITY";
private EditText editTextTitle;
private EditText editTextDescription;
private NumberPicker numberPickerPriority;
private EditText editTextPrice;
private EditText editTextQuantity;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_note);
    editTextTitle = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_title);
    editTextDescription = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_description);
    editTextPrice = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_price);
    editTextQuantity = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_quantity);
    numberPickerPriority = findViewById(R.id.number_picker_priority);
    numberPickerPriority.setMinValue(1);
    numberPickerPriority.setMaxValue(10);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_close);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.hasExtra(EXTRA_ID)) {
        setTitle("Edit Note");
        editTextTitle.setText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_TITLE));
        editTextDescription.setText(intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_DESCRIPTION));
        numberPickerPriority.setValue(intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_PRIORITY, 1));
        editTextPrice.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d", intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_PRICE, 1)));
        editTextQuantity.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d", intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_QUANTITY, 1)));

    } else {
        setTitle("Add Note");
    }
}
private void saveNote() {
    String title = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
    String description = editTextDescription.getText().toString();
    int price = Integer.parseInt(editTextPrice.getText().toString());
    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(editTextQuantity.getText().toString());
    int priority = numberPickerPriority.getValue();
    if (title.trim().isEmpty() || description.trim().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, title);
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_PRICE, price);
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_QUANTITY, quantity);
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_DESCRIPTION, description);
    data.putExtra(EXTRA_PRIORITY, priority);
    int id = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_ID, -1);
    if (id != -1) {
        data.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, id);
    }
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    finish();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.add_note_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.save_note:
            saveNote();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

and the corresponding relevant part in ActivityMain.java:

```
 adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new NoteAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(Note note) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddEditNoteActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_ID, note.getId());
            intent.putExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_TITLE, note.getTitle());
            intent.putExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_PRICE, note.getPrice());
            intent.putExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_QUANTITY, note.getQuantity());
            intent.putExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_DESCRIPTION, note.getDescription());
            intent.putExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_PRIORITY, note.getPriority());
            startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_NOTE_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == ADD_NOTE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String title = data.getStringExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_TITLE);
        String description = data.getStringExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_DESCRIPTION);
        int price = data.getIntExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_PRICE, 0);
        int quantity = data.getIntExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_QUANTITY, 0);
        int priority = data.getIntExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_PRIORITY, 1);
        Note note = new Note(title, description, priority, price, quantity);
        noteViewModel.insert(note);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Product saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (requestCode == EDIT_NOTE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        int id = data.getIntExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_ID, -1);

        if (id == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Product can't be updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        String title = data.getStringExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_TITLE);
        String description = data.getStringExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_DESCRIPTION);
        int priority = data.getIntExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_PRIORITY, 1);
        int price = data.getIntExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_PRICE, 0);
        int quantity = data.getIntExtra(AddEditNoteActivity.EXTRA_QUANTITY, 0);

        Note note = new Note(title, description, priority, price, quantity);
        note.setId(id);
        noteViewModel.update(note);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Product updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Product not saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The activity_add_note.xml is as follows:

```
tools:context=".AddEditNoteActivity">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
    android:hint="Add/Edit a new product:"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:textColor="#243949" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:hint="Item Name"
    android:inputType="text" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_price"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:hint="Price:"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_quantity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:hint="Quantity"
    android:inputType="numberSigned" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:hint="State"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:text="Priority:"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/number_picker_priority"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```